# Editor role isn't seeing specific post type posts with only post_type parameter

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, user-roles, editor

The editor role is able to open following URL:

https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?booking-status=booked&post_type=booking

But not able to open following URL:

https://example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=booking

I am facing this amazing problem as when I pass other parameters with `post_type` then it is opening custom post type edit screen but when I only pass `post_type` then it is not opening.

This is only happening with editor role.

```
<?php

function create_booking_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Bookings','framework'),
        'singular_name' => __( 'booking','framework' ),
        'add_new' => __('Add New','framework'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New booking','framework'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit booking','framework'),
        'new_item' => __('New booking','framework'),
        'view_item' => __('View booking','framework'),
        'search_items' => __('Search booking','framework'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No booking found','framework'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No booking found in Trash','framework'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array(
        'title','editor','thumbnail','revisions','author','page-attributes'),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => __('booking', 'framework') )
    );

    register_post_type('booking',$args);
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code creating the custom post type.

Comment: @MaxYudin, here is code: http://textuploader.com/58c9d

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem. Do you use any user roles managing plugins or custom code? Also, where do you get `booking-status=booked` query in the URL?

Comment: @MaxYudin, additionally I have created custom taxonomies like booking-status, booking-types, booking-features etc. I am using user role editor plugin.

Comment: So, please edit your question adding necessary information including taxonomies and editor role settings.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make custom user meta fields.

Links these metafields to a custom category linked to your custom post type.

Use this code for a checkbox feeling:

```
<input  type="checkbox" id="category-<?php echo $post_type->term_id ?>" <?php if($user_cats[0] && in_array( $post_type->term_id, $user_cats[0] )) echo 'checked=checked';?> 
            name="categories[]" value="<?php echo $post_type->term_id;?>"/>
```

Every custom category you make in the custom post type will be linked to the users profile. this way you can assign posts to a certain user.